# Print POST request for debugging

Tags: android, debugging, http, post

How do you print a POST request for debugging in Android?

I'm using either [HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) or [HttpURLConection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

The intent is to give the POST request to another member of the team so they can reproduce it in another platform.

Comment: What are you using to generate the post request? You dont need to print it to look at its contents, thats what the debugger is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to look at bytes sent over the wire you need Fiddler (on Windows) or Wireshark (on Linux).